# I want to re format my css and jquery code for dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following code working fine for dropdown menu
but i need to modify css and jquery.

> Need to increase the main box and decrease the 1st icon row

but when `i try` to `decrease the width` it is `decrease whole box width`

please guide.
FIDDLE LINK
`http://fiddle.jshell.net/6pLPn/`

[image]
code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo">
            JQUERY DEMO
            </div>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="nav-link">

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- Clickable Nav -->
        <div class="click-nav">
            <ul class="no-js">
                <li>
                    <a class="clicker"><img src="img/i-1.png" alt="Icon">Profile</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/i-2.png" alt="Icon">Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/i-3.png" alt="Icon">Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/i-4.png" alt="Icon">Privacy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/i-5.png" alt="Icon">Help</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/i-6.png" alt="Icon">Sign out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /Clickable Nav -->

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(function() {
            // Clickable Dropdown
            $('.click-nav > ul').toggleClass('no-js js');
            $('.click-nav .js ul').hide();
            $('.click-nav .js').click(function(e) {
                $('.click-nav .js ul').slideToggle(200);
                $('.clicker').toggleClass('active');
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
            $(document).click(function() {
                if ($('.click-nav .js ul').is(':visible')) {
                    $('.click-nav .js ul', this).slideUp();
                    $('.clicker').removeClass('active');
                }
            });
        });
        </script>




    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of everything here is set on the container div `<div class="click-nav">`.
That has a width of 200px defined in the CSS.

The `<a>` tags inside the `<li>` items are set to `display: block` causing them to fill the width of that parent container.

To make the 'first icon row' smaller, you can target it with the `.clicker` class.

```
.clicker {
    width: 100px; /* or use a percentage like 50% */
}
```

And to make the 'main box' bigger you can add a width larger than 200px to `.click-nav ul li ul` which is already targeted in the CSS.  E.g.

```
.click-nav ul li ul {
    width: 250px; /* or use a percentage like 125% */
}
```

[Updated your fiddle here.](http://fiddle.jshell.net/6pLPn/4/)

Is that what you meant?  It was hard to understand exactly what the problem was.

Comment: Thanks a lot exactly what i need , sorry for miss conversation.
But it only reduces width when i click on same 1st line then also it is expanding.

need to reduce length of 1st column and how much length it has on that part click should work for expand menu.

Comment: You didn't actually include the jQuery library in your fiddle, so it was falling back to the non-js version, which is to display the menu on hover.  I've added jQuery library to an updated fiddle here http://fiddle.jshell.net/6pLPn/5/.  If you take a look at that, can you then explain what the problem is?